# Changing the System Login Using Email

Tags: php, email

For default, the script I use username to login. However, there may be someone who forgot their username and I want to give the option to log in using email.

The script below can I edit log in using the email by replacing `username` into `email`.

However, after a successful login, which is displayed on the account instead of the username, but the email address.

Could you give a solution to this problem?

**My Code:**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LogIn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='message'>You're logged in !!</div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    $ousername = '';
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
            $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
        }
        else
        {
            $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        }
        $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
        $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
        if($dn['password']==sha1($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            $form = false;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
            if(isset($_POST['memorize']) and $_POST['memorize']=='yes')
            {
                $one_year = time()+(60*60*24*365);
                setcookie('username', $_POST['username'], $one_year);
                setcookie('password', sha1($password), $one_year);
            }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>LogIn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div class='message'>Login Success</div>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
            $form = true;
            $message = 'Username and password not match';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $form = true;
    }
    if($form)
    {
?>
</body>
</html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>LogIn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
if(isset($message))
{
    echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
}
?>

    <form method='post'>
        <div class='login'>
            <label for='username'>Username</label><input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br />
            <label for='password'>Password</label><input type='password' name='password' id='password' /><br />
            <input type='submit' value='Masuk' />
        </div>
    </form>

<?php
    }
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a query like `select id,password,username FROM tbl WHERE username='username' OR email = 'email'`

So this query work in both case either he want to log in using user name or email address.

After that if password match then assign username (which we fetched recently using select query) to session..

I hope i understand your question. right?

Comment: OK, Then what did happen? and what you want to do ? explain me in detail so i can help you.